# XDSoft DateTimePicker wrong week days

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I use [XDSoft DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) quite a lot in my projects.
Recently i found out that week days are wrong. (Today) 3 september 2015 on calendar it is as a friday but it should be thursday.

Is there some quick fix i can do to move one day ?

I tried to change:

> dayOfWeekStart

but i want "saturday" and s"unday" at the end of week.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have to ask a question in a way so that users can see or reproduce the issue .[This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  helps you to ask a question. and update the question

Comment: Well, i did it this way. Just take a look at website and you will see that according to datepicker today is friday. But in reality today is wednesday.

Comment: that may be timezone issue , for me today  is thursday

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **dayOfWeekStart: 1**

for example:

```
$('#datetimepickerTest').datetimepicker({
    inline:true,
    step:10,
    format:'Y-m-d H:i',
    lang:'tr',
    dayOfWeekStart: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, on page is correct day. Well, still don't know why it's happened on my scripts, but i found solution:

Change dayOfWeekStart for 1, and then change order of dayOfWeek:

```
dayOfWeek:["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
```

By doing this "saturday" and "Sunday" is at the end of row, but we moved one day.